# Disable static file caching in Tornado

Tags: python, caching, tornado, static-files

By default, Tornado puts a `Cache-Control: public` header on any file served by a `StaticFileHandler`. How can this be changed to `Cache-Control: no-cache`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looking into the tornado/web.py it seems that the easiest way is to subclass the StaticFileHandler and override the set_extra_headers method.

```
def set_extra_headers(self, path):
    self.set_header("Cache-control", "no-cache")
```

Answer (score 48):

The accepted answer does not work for Chrome.  Subclass `StaticFileHandler` using the following:

```
class MyStaticFileHandler(tornado.web.StaticFileHandler):
    def set_extra_headers(self, path):
        # Disable cache
        self.set_header('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0')
```

Comment: This worked for me on Safari and Chrome for Mac OS. +1